# ActionScript MouseEvent's CLICK vs. DOUBLE_CLICK

Tags: actionscript-3, click, mouseevent, double-click

is it not possible to have both CLICK and DOUBLE_CLICK on the same display object?  i'm trying to have both for the stage where double clicking the stage adds a new object and clicking once on the stage deselects a selected object.

it appears that DOUBLE_CLICK will execute both itself as well as the first CLICK functions in the path toward DOUBLE CLICK (mouse down, mouse up, click, mouse down, mouse up, double click).

in other languages i've programmed with there was a built-in timers that set the two apart.  is this not available in AS3?

---

### UPDATE

here's some code.  essentially what i would like is have one or the other, not both with double click

```
stage.doubleClickEnabled = true;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, twoClicks, false, 0, true);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, oneClick, false, 0, true);

function oneClick(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
    trace("One CLICK");
    }

function twoClicks(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
    trace("Two CLICKS");
    }

//oneClick trace = "One CLICK"
//twoClicks trace = "One CLICK Two CLICKS" (instead of just Two CLICKS)
```

Comment: You have to do it yourself. Double click is pretty useless in practice. I mean, if you want to listen to a double click, it's most likely because you want to assign an action to a single click and a different (and separate) one to a double click.

Comment: yeah, it's something i've taken for granted with other development SDKs like iPhone tapping.  but after several hours i managed to enable click and double click with actionscript without having to resort to any timers.

Comment: I dont really see the issue here. Clicking once to deselect shouldn't interfere with trying to double click. So what if the single click event gets fired? Do you want to retain the possible selection when a double click occurs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you could use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

It'd look something like this:

```
const var DOUBLE_CLICK_SPEED:int = 10;
var mouseTimeout;

function handleClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (mouseTimeout != undefined) {
        twoClicks();
        clearTimeout(mouseTimeout);
        mouseTimeout = undefined;
    } else {
        function handleSingleClick():void {
            oneClick();
            mouseTimeout = undefined;
        }
        mouseTimeout = setTimeout(handleSingleClick, DOUBLE_CLICK_SPEED);
    }
}

function oneClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("One CLICK");
}

function twoClicks(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("Two CLICKS");
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick, false, 0, true);
```

Comment: Yeah, the only problem is that it doesn't consider the user configuration in the system control panel, anyway, it works, voted up :)

Comment: Is that even possible to access in Flash?

Comment: The call to the actual clickHandlers is missing the MouseEvent and the DOUBLE_CLICK_SPEED needs to be much higher, around 300ms. Other than that works fine, +1

Comment: I had to add a double click handler too:    stage.doubleClickEnabled = true;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, handleClick, false, 0, true);

Answer (score 5):

Did you set `.doubleClickEnabled` to true?

You should also take a look [here](http://www.charglerode.com/blog/?p=54).

Comment: yes, of course. otherwise double clicking just wouldn't work.  i've update my question with code so you can see what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer Wallacoloo - thanks for that. I have just implemented your solution and refined a few points, so I'd thought I'd put it here for future reference (and of course the benefit of the overflow community!). Firstly, I couldn't test for undefined on the uint returned by setTimeout, so I replaced the undefined conditional with an == 0 conditional. Secondly, I wanted to commit the logic of a single click instantaneously (just makes for a more pleasant user interface), so I've done a bit of reshuffling:

```
        if (mouseTimeout != 0) {
            // clicked within the timeout, handle as double click

            // rollback single click logic
            rollbackSingleClickHandler(e);
            // commit double click logic
            dblClickHandler(e);

            clearTimeOut(mouseTimeout);
            mouseTimeout = 0;
        } else {
            // first click of a click sequence

            // commit single click logic
            singleClickHandler(e); 

            function clearTime():void {
                mouseTimeout = 0;
            }

            // register a timeout for a potential double click
            mouseTimeout = setTimeout(clearTime, DOUBLE_CLICK_SPEED);
        }
```